# How to use a conditional useSelector assigned to a single variable based on function param passed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to have a single variable, selectorValue, but the useSelector selector function changes depending on what the passed function param is.

For example, I want to either get the selector for physical books or ebooks books, so I'd pass in physical or ebooks as the target. It would then either use my physical books selector or the ebooks one.

```
const myDataHook = ({ targetSelector: string }) => {
  // Doesn't work, just an example of the condtional selector
  // Example is only 2, but real case is 4+
  const selectorValue: string = useSelector(() => {
    if (targetSelector === SELECTOR_A) return getSelector_A_Values();
    else {
      return getSelector_B_Values();
    }
  });
  ...
}
```

I can't do a if statement and for different useSelectors since they're hooks and must be called on the top level. Nor does useEffect work, since again, top level.

Is what I want even possible. I don't want to declare N selectors when I'm only going to be using a single one for the hook.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, if the `selectorValueTarget` is a string you receive, why can you not just access it via `useSelector((state)=>state[selectorValueTarget]);`

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear, it's not possible to use direct state[key] to get the values. Hence why I needed conditional selectors

Comment: Improve your data structure.Combine your four sub data into one named `something`, and use one useSelector get `something`.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a more representative [mcve] of the code you are actually trying to use and have an issue with.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that. You can write any logic you want *within* that `useSelector` call, your code is perfectly valid. You could not write `if` statements *around* a `useSelector` call, but *inside* of it, that is totally fine.

The only thing you have to care about is that changing the `targetSelector` value also needs to rerender your component, or the new selector will never be executed. So `targetSelector` needs to be some kind of state as well, local or global.